# Better syntax for non-inline code blocks

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Every time I post a code block on SO, I'm faced with having to manually go through every line and indent it by the appropriate # of spaces to get it to be recognized correctly as a code block.  Sometimes I avoid posting code for this reason, cause it's a hassle.  I've tried select all & <TAB> like I can do in my IDE/editor, but no cigar.

I would love to have some other tags to indicate non-inline code blocks that allow me to just add a tag at the beginning and end of my code. <code></code> or {code}{/code} or something similar.  Or, if there's some other way already that I don't know about, I would love to know.

Comment: Ctrl+K is your friend...

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that in one of the duplicates. Yeah, that's awesome! Wish I had known sooner :)